# How to add records from Django (version 1.5) admin when the database (PostgreSQL) is partitioned?

Tags: django, postgresql

I would like to know whether it is possible to add new records to the database from Django (version 1.5) admin when the database (PostgreSQL) has been partitioned?

More specifically, in my database I have partitioned (via the use of triggers) a table named `Category` into two partitions named `category_01` and `category_02`.

After I was finished with partitioning the table, I tried to insert new records into it but kept getting the following error:

`'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`.

Does anybody have an idea on how to solve this problem? I have tried to add a custom `save()` method into the model as well, but to no avail. Would could be the simplest solution here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After 2 days of research, I was finally able to solve this issue on my own. My solution was to override the `save(..)` method in my model like so:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
   #custom save method
   #pdb.set_trace()
   from django.db import connection
   connection.features.can_return_id_from_insert = False
   print "save"

   super(your model name here, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Thanks for the Django docs and PostgreSQL docs, https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/django-users/-AT4PLOmWAE and https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10467 for helping me solve the issue!